# Flutter: Network proxy is ineffective on Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, proxy

I use ShadowSocksR as a network proxy, the proxy address is like `http://localhost:1080.`

For my Flutter app, on Android and iOS, everything works fine with ShandowSocksR turned on, when I visit websites that show the visitor's ip (e.g. http://www.svlik.com/t/ipapi/ip.php) it successfully shows the ip address of my proxy server.

But on windows, no matter how I set it up, it always shows my own ip address, and the proxy does not work when sending network requests.

Is there any way to solve it?

Flutter (3.0.4, on Microsoft Windows)
[Windows Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j70Ot.jpg)